# Dummy Mobile number and email utilities for Testing

Tags: java, testing

I am writing code and testing for Mobile and Email code verification for a  User account creation. Is there any utility that can be used for my Testing which I can use for mobile number and email.

Answer (score -1):

For the purpose of full integration testing of emails and/or phone numbers, implement an override feature, where you can configure an email and/or a phone number in a configuration file, to be used instead of the email and/or a phone number that is in the data.

Then, when testing, configure it use use your own email and/or phone number. That way you can verify that email, text, and/or phone call happens, and you can verify the content of the email/text.